# Blank columns while exporting csv

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a VisualForce page to Export as Csv. In this I have some columns which renders based on a Boolean value. I have added a similar code below,

```
<td><apex:outPutlabel value="Prioritisation ANF"  rendered="TRUE"/>  </td> <td><apex:outPutlabel value="Classification CF"  rendered="FALSE"/>  </td> <td><apex:outPutlabel value="Prioritisation CF"  rendered="FALSE"/>  </td> <td <apex:outPutlabel value="Classification HBV"  rendered="TRUE"/>  </td>
```

When it exports, it shows Blank columns as in below screenshot. For each (Render=false) it creates a blank space. it looks fine in VisualForce page though.

[image]

Any idea to overcome this.?

Comment: can you post your apex class which is creating csv file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not work fine in Visualforce. It happens to render okay only because of the default styles, but the columns are still there. They would probably render differently in the Lightning Design System. Regardless, to fix this situation, you need to put the  `td` elements inside the conditional render:

```
<apex:outputPanel rendered="false"><td>text...</td></apex:outputText>
```